# is python the preferred language for mobile applications?

Tags: python, mobile

a lot of my friends are using Python to build their mobile applications and games.

is python the preferred language for mobile applications for developers? if so, why?

Comment: "a lot of my friends".  Sounds like it's "preferred" by your friends.  What more what you like to know?

Comment: well i was wondering if there were any libraries/frameworks written in python with the mobile development process in mind. i figure that's why my friends use the language.

Comment: Perhaps you should as your friends for the libraries they use.  Would that be better than asking anonymous folks here?  You could get more information from them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, there is no preferred language for mobile development. Each mobile platform has its own supported language or set of supported languages. Android is programmed primarily with Java (although development in C++ and Python are also supported), while the iPhone is programmed with Objective-C. A common theme in mobile is to implement the core functionality of the application as a webservice, and then to implement a UI for a specific mobile platform that is a thin client to the web service. While the UI will be written in whichever language(s) are supported by the platform, the language that you use for the webservice can be whatever programming language(s) you choose to run on your webserver. If you use a cloud computing service, then that would be whatever languages are supported by that service (e.g. if you use Google AppEngine, then Python and Java are both supported languages).

Answer (score 5):

No. Python is an excellent language, but there is nothing about it makes it especially preferred for mobile development.